# Is there a way to update the value of a key in a dictionary, if the value of the dictionary is a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have four lists of special character strings eg '™'. I am storing them in a dictionary as the value to the keys 1 through 4.

I am trying to loop through all items in each of the dictionary's lists and then update each value to its utf-8 encoded equivalent.
Here's what I have so far:

```
li1 = ['€','‚','ƒ','„','…','†','ˆ','‰']
li2 = ['Š','‹','Œ','Ž']
li3 = ['‘','’','“','”','•','–','—','˜','™']
li4 = ['š','›','œ','ž','Ÿ']

uni_dic = {
    '1':li1,
    '2':li2,
    '3':li3,
    '4':li4
}

for key in uni_dic:
    for val in uni_dic[key]:
        uni_dic.update({key,val.encode('utf-8')})
```

This returns a 'ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required'

Comment: I think this part should be uni_dic.update({key:val.encode('utf-8')})  replace the , with :

Comment: `{value  ,  value}` is a `set`. `{key  : value}` is a `dict`

Comment: you getting the syntax error because you call `update` with another dictionary. 
`uni_dic.update(key: value.encode("utf-8")`

However, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish because the existing code just modifies the existing dictionary. No lookup or translation is accomplished.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A one-line solution to your question is:

```py
uni_dic = {key:[val.encode('utf-8') for val in charList] for key, charList in uni_dic.items()}
```

To get the same result with a minimal modification to the code in your question, you could do this:

```py
li1 = ['€','‚','ƒ','„','…','†','ˆ','‰']
li2 = ['Š','‹','Œ','Ž']
li3 = ['‘','’','“','”','•','–','—','˜','™']
li4 = ['š','›','œ','ž','Ÿ']

uni_dic = {
    '1':li1,
    '2':li2,
    '3':li3,
    '4':li4
}

for key in uni_dic:
    charList = uni_dic[key]
    for i, val in enumerate(charList):
        charList[i] = val.encode('utf-8')
[print(charList) for charList in uni_dic.values()]
```

Output:

```
[b'\xe2\x82\xac', b'\xe2\x80\x9a', b'\xc6\x92', b'\xe2\x80\x9e', b'\xe2\x80\xa6', b'\xe2\x80\xa0', b'\xcb\x86', b'\xe2\x80\xb0']
[b'\xc5\xa0', b'\xe2\x80\xb9', b'\xc5\x92', b'\xc5\xbd']
[b'\xe2\x80\x98', b'\xe2\x80\x99', b'\xe2\x80\x9c', b'\xe2\x80\x9d', b'\xe2\x80\xa2', b'\xe2\x80\x93', b'\xe2\x80\x94', b'\xcb\x9c', b'\xe2\x84\xa2']
[b'\xc5\xa1', b'\xe2\x80\xba', b'\xc5\x93', b'\xc5\xbe', b'\xc5\xb8']
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the last three lines and write:

```
for key, values in uni_dic.items():
    uni_dic[key] = [string.encode('utf-8') for string in values]
```

or in one line:

```
uni_dic = {key: [string.encode('utf-8') for string in uni_dic[key]] for key in uni_dic}
```

uni_dic}

Comment: Did you mean for string in values for the first suggestion?

Comment: yes, i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can create another list like below:

```py
for key in uni_dic:
    uni_dic[key] = [val.encode('utf-8') for val in uni_dic[key]]
```

If you want to do it in-place:

```py
for key in uni_dic:
    for idx, val in enumerate(uni_dic[key]):
        uni_dic[key][idx] = val.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is that you're specifying your update dict as `{key,val.encode('utf-8')}` (which is actually a `set`) instead of `{key: val.encode('utf-8')}`.  However, it's a bit silly to use `update` to update a single key anyway, and they way you're looping through the list, you'll just be overwriting the list repeatedly with each element in turn (ultimately ending up with the last item).

Instead, build a new list out of the encoded values, and assign the *entire list* to `uni_dic[key]`:

```
for key in uni_dic:
    encoded_vals = []
    for val in uni_dic[key]:
        encoded_vals.append(val.encode('utf-8'))
    uni_dic[key] = encoded_vals
```

Using a list comprehension to build `encoded_vals` gets you the much more concise:

```
for key in uni_dic:
    uni_dic[key] = [val.encode('utf-8') for val in uni_dic[key]]
```

And using a dictionary comprehension with `dict.items()` makes it even simpler:

```
uni_dic = {k: [val.encode('utf-8') for val in v] for k, v in uni_dic.items()}
```

Comment: For your first solution, I would put the encoded_vals = [] outside of both for loops, so that it iterates throughout each key and that key's values, giving a complete list of every encoded value not just the first.